# How to break at a constructor of base class using gdb?

Tags: c++, gdb, breakpoints

My main cpp file is as:

```
class UnifiedDirListQuery : public UnifiedQuery{
public:
    UnifiedDirListQuery(){
        //do something-------------line 12
    }
}
//other code

int main( void ){
    UnifiedQuery *query = new UnifiedDirListQuery();//-----line 56
    //do something
    delete query;
}
```

And the `UnifiedQuery` is declared and defined in `unified.h` and `unified.cpp` respectively. When I debug this program in gdb:

```
gdb: b 56
gdb: r
gdb: s
```

the program jumped to line 12. How to go to `unified.cpp` and jump to the `Ctor` of base class `UnifiedQuery` if the ctor is defined in `unified.cpp : line 25` for instance.

**UPDATES**

For the answer `break UnifiedDirListQuery::UnifiedDirListQuery` the gdb complains that:

```
(gdb) b UnifiedDirListQuery::UnifiedDirListQuery
[0] cancel
[1] all
?HERE
?HERE
> 1
Note: breakpoint -1 (disabled) also set at pc 0x0.
Breakpoint 1 at 0x0
Note: breakpoints -1 (disabled) and 1 also set at pc 0x0.
Breakpoint 2 at 0x0
warning: Multiple breakpoints were set.
Use the "delete" command to delete unwanted breakpoints.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /...(the path)/src/base/unified_album_list.cgi
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Error accessing memory address 0x0: Input/output error.
```

For the answer `b file:line`, gdb just ignore it and went through the program without stop. BTW: actually the definition of the ctor is in a file named `unified.h`, implicity declared as an inline function since it is in a header file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also

```
break UnifiedDirListQuery::UnifiedDirListQuery
```

Notice also that gdb has tab completion, so you don't have to type everything.

Comment: Does the class live in any namespace? In gdb you need to fully qualify. Also, did you try tab completion (for overload resolution)? Oh and if the constructor is inlined, it might not be possible to break there at all. Try a debug build.

Comment: No, I used 'tab' to complete, and the constructor is inline, perhaps this is a good reason for the failure. PS: And what is a debug build?

Comment: Debug build means that you disable optimizations and enable debug symbols, i.e. compile with `-O0 -g` (for gcc)

Comment: @arne isn't -O0 the default?

Comment: @Liam that depends on your build system. Many IDEs already have some kind of optimization configured in default project templates. Hence, if you add `-O0 -g` to your options, any prior `-O` flags are overridden.

Answer (score 0):

`break unified.cpp:25` should do the trick, to break at line 25 for example
Especially if you have more than one file, you must give the name of the file where you want to break. See [here](http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbbreak.html#BLINE) for more information